# Get Text of every row in a Paged Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

I have a paged gridview. I want to get the text of every row and put that text into an array. However, I only get the text for the visible rows, not the entire dataset. I can't just get the data from the datasource because the gridview is populated by two different databases. How could I get every row's text - visible or not visible? I'm trying to put the text in an array as follows:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.Load
    For j As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If GridView1.Rows(j).Cells(3).Text = "Yes" Then
            loginoper = loginoper & GridView1.Rows(j).Cells(1).Text & ","

        Else
            logoutoper = logoutoper & GridView1.Rows(j).Cells(1).Text & ","

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is another reason why I just pull my data into data tables and populate items from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do processing against every row of a GridView in the RowDataBound event. First, you'll have to check the .Row.RowType property of the passed-in GridViewRowEventArgs -- it'll be Header, DataRow, Footer, etc. Then, if it is a DataRow, add it's data to your array with whatever additional logic you need.